# Searching for a one page overview widget

Tags: widgets, navigation

I am currently using the Lodestar theme. My website is built up in a way that the navigation bar at the top leads you to different pages which have a one-page static structure. 
To allow for navigation in each one of those pages I am searching for a widget that allows for inner-page navigation. Meaning that if you click on a title in this navigation widget you jump in the same page to a specific block.

I have an example here that might give you an idea what exactly I am looking for:

http://globallearningfactory.com/industrie-4-0/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add a menu item whose link goes to a specific section on the same page or a section on a different page. This works with any WordPress menu, which you can create and edit by clicking Appearance > Menus in the WordPress admin panel.

This technique involves two steps: adding a unique ID to the target section in a Lodestar theme layout, then adding the link with that unique ID to your WordPress menu.

Add the unique ID to a menu item:

1. On the WordPress admin menu, click Appearance > Menus and make sure the menu you want to use is displayed.
2. In the left column expand the Custom links category.
3. Enter the full URL of the target page in which the section occurs, followed by the pound sign and your ID. For example, if the section occurs on the page https://www.example.com/goals/, then your URL would be:
   https://www.example.com/goals/#my-unique-id
4. Enter whatever link text you want your menu item to display.
   Click Add to menu.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. My plan is to have a separate menu on every page which lets you jump to specific section in the same page. In addition to a menu in the top which lets you navigate to different pages.

Comment: For this purpose I advise you to use the Conditional Menus plugin. Check here:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/conditional-menus/